# Numba: How to turn on/off just-in-time compilation programmatically (setting NUMBA_DISABLE_JIT environment variable)?

Tags: python, jit, numba

I have written a script which is intended to test the efficacy of the `@numba.jit` decorators that I've added to several functions. I want to first exercise the annotated functions without the just-in-time compilation, then do it again with the `@numba.jit` decorators in play, in order to then compare the two results.

I've tried doing this by modifying the value of the `NUMBA_DISABLE_JIT` environment variable via `os.environ`, but I'm not sure yet that this is having the desired effect. For example:

```
# run first without and then with numba's just-in-time compilation
for flag in [1, 0]:

    # enable/disable numba's just-in-time compilation
    os.environ["NUMBA_DISABLE_JIT"] = str(flag)

    # time an arbitrary number of iterations of the JIT decorated function
    start = time.time()
    for _ in range(1000):
        expensive_function()
    end = time.time()

    # display the elapsed time
    if flag == 0:
        preposition = "with"
    else:
        preposition = "without"
    print("Elapsed time " + preposition + " numba: {t}".format(t=(end - start)))
```

Is the setting of the environment variable `DISABLE_NUMBA_JIT` above actually having the effect of disabling/enabling the JIT compilation of all functions decorated with `@numba.jit` as I assume? If not then is there a better way to skin this cat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that flag only has impact on the first call of `expensive_function` so isn't doing what you you'd like.

With numba you can always access the original python function with `.py_func`, so that could be a simpler way to do this

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def expensive_function(arr):
    ans = 0.0
    for a in arr:
        ans += a
    return ans

arr = np.random.randn(1_000_000)

In [21]: %timeit expensive_function(arr)
# 1.51 ms ± 24.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit expensive_function.py_func(arr)
# 134 ms ± 11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 7):

Import config from numba and set it to True to disable @jit and False to enable @jit.

```
from numba import jit, config

config.DISABLE_JIT = True
```